# What does a comma mean inside an 'if' statement?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < g.size(); ++i)
    for (auto j = 0; j < g.size(); ++j) if (g[i][j] == 0) dfs(g, i, j), ++regions;
return regions;
```

I don't like one line code. What does the code execute in the `if()`?

I am confused by the "," sign.

Usually I would write it as:

```
  for (auto i = 0; i < g.size(); ++i)
  {
      for (auto j = 0; j < g.size(); ++j)
      {
          if (g[i][j] == 0)
          {
             dfs(g, i, j)
          }
          ,++regions; // I am not sure what to do here. Inside the "if" scope??
      }
} 
  return regions;
```

Comment: The second code snippet is not balanced - there are three opening `{`s and two closing `}`s - it is missing a `}`.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475032/comma-operator-in-if-condition

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The programmer has used the [*comma operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/560648) to provide two unrelated expressions in a single statement. Because it's a single statement, both expressions are "inside" the `if` condition.

It's a poor hack, which would be better done with actual `{}` braces surrounding two statements.

Your example is not equivalent; it should be:

```
if (g[i][j] == 0) 
{
   dfs(g, i, j);
   ++regions;
}
```

Comment: ohh god, why why why would anyone write this code. Thanks

Comment: @Gilad Trying to be clever, most likely! And failing.

Comment: @Gilad a very smart programmer once said *Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.* What I took from this was write the stupidest possible code that can meet the requirements. Even if I can debug sneaky code, the person I hand it off to to maintain might not.

Comment: @user4581301 so there is another case where he uses it like so

Comment: void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& g, int i, int j) {
  if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < g.size() && j < g.size() && g[i][j] == 0) {
    g[i][j] = 1;
    dfs(g, i - 1, j), dfs(g, i + 1, j), dfs(g, i, j - 1), dfs(g, i, j + 1);
  }
}

Comment: I wonder if you can use this in loops too... Nope, you can't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a habit of old school programmers due to small monitor resolution (25 rows 80 columns) code was writing  as short as possible. More code on one page better readability. Try read modern code on such monitor and you will see how many empty rows in it.

Comment: @Constantinos, you can use the comma operator in any expression, and you can use an expression statement as the body of a loop, so I’m curious what you mean can’t be used in loops.

Comment: Of course, that hack is especially useful for macros, which one also should avoid assiduously.

Comment: @prl: I tried a simple while loop with the comma operator that increments the counter to break out of the loop, but the clang refused to compile. Maybe I did it wrong...

Comment: @AndreySv Yep. Common in C. It eliminates the need to put braces in. Perfectly legible for anyone used to the comma operator idiom so long as the if and predicate are also indented. Less common practice these days so peeps aren't familiar with it. Code s/b written to be as clear as possible to as many programmers as possible. Within reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator  So true. Reducing use of macros was a principal driver for me switching to C++.

Comment: In C I sometimes do `return log("bla"), E_FOO;` to save on vertical space, which means that when viewing the code, more of the function can be taken in at once. (I don't use that sort of error handing in C++)

Comment: @AndreySv Such programmers have had some thirty years to break that habit, i.e. since before C++ even existed.

Comment: @doug: Although the code is perfectly legible to me (hence the fast answer) I maintain that this is _not_ good code. So the two are not one and the same.

Comment: @Andrey Sv I suppose you are not a fan of a tab spacing of 8 then ([whether or not they are actual physical TAB characters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=8m49s))?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Its only [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma) no more no less.

Comment: @AndreySv Who claimed it's non-standard?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, what is "good" code. When I come across a series of expressions separated by a comma it's immediately obvious they are only being used for side effects, unless the result of a comma expression is actually used which I find to not be intuitive.  To me good code is something where the structure, naming, etc. conveys useful information about the program. I don't use the comma operator to chain side effect expressions these days but mostly because too few are familiar with it and may be confused.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. The mark of true cleverness is that the result looks simple, elegant, and obvious. Anything that looks "clever" actually isn't.