# C++ for with multiple control statements using comma operator

Tags: c++, for-loop, comma-operator

How does comma operator if it is used in a 'for loop' for writing multiple control statements?
i tried

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < 3, y < 4; ++x, ++y) {
                cout << x << " " << y << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

and it seems like only the last expression is evaluated. Ty

Comment: comma operator here works the same as everywhere else: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [comma operator in if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475032/comma-operator-in-if-condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) works. Its 1st operand `x < 3` is evaluated, then the result is discarded; then the 2nd operand `y < 4` is evaluated and the value is returned as the return value of the comma operator. `x < 3` has not any effects here.

You might want to use `operator&&` or `operator||` for this case, e.g. `x < 3 && y < 4` or `x < 3 || y < 4` based on your intent.