# C language and operators

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, comma-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=2;

  if(i==3,4)
  { 
      printf("If block");
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Else block");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Why is this code returning "If block" ?``

Comment: what is 3,4 supposed to do?

Comment: `if (i==3,4) { ... }` is the same as `i==3; if (4) { ... }`

Comment: I think you will find the function is _returning_ 0. It is _printing_ "If block" because the expression `i==3,4` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 3):

The expression in the `if` statement:

```
(i==3,4)
```

Contains the *comma operator*.  It evaluates its left operand, discards its value, then evaluated the right operand which is its result.  This operator also has lower precedence than the equality operator `==`, so this parses as:

```
((i==3),4)
```

So `i==3` is first evaluated.  Since `i` has the value 2 the comparison is false resulting in `i==3` evaluating to 0.  This value is discarded.  Then `4` is evaluated which becomes the value of the entire expression.  Since this value is non-zero, the `if` block is true, so "If block" is printed.

Answer (score 3):

In the condition of the if statement

```
if(i==3,4)
```

there is used the comma operator.

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
> expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
> of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
> has its type and value

That is the above if statement can be equivalently written like

```
if( ( i==3 ), ( 4 ))
```

So according to the quote from the C Standard the left operand ( i == 3 ) is evaluated as a void expression that is its result is discarded. And the result of the whole expression is the value of the right operand that is of the expression `( 4 )`. As this expression is not equal to 0 then the whole condition is evaluated as logical true and the sub-statement of the if statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Why is this code returning "If block" ?``"*

The explanation of *why* the expression `if(i==3,4)` causes execution flow to go to the true branch is provided in good detail in the other answers.   In short the idea that it *evaluates its first operand and discards the result,* Then uses the second operand to evaluate as the *condition*.

But, some might ask is this useful?

One use is to force a [side effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) prior to deciding which branch to flow to.

For example

```
if (numeric_read(str, &err), !err) 
//           ^                 ^ result 'err' of side effect used in if evaluation.
             ^
//  causes side effect by call function which assigns value to err.
```

([credit, in comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475043/645128))

The side effect here populates `err`, then discards the logical result of the call in the first argument.  The value assigned to `err` is then used to select the branch.