# A beginner at coding, stuck at a code to identify a Prime Number in C++... Can someone please rectify the error in this code?

Tags: c++

Apparently, the for loop is executed everytime which changes the value of bool to false, and always show that the given number is composite

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    bool Prime=true;
    cout << "Enter the number to check for Prime Number: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b == 0, 1)
    {
        Prime=false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (a = 2; a < b; a++)
        {
            if (b % a == 0)
            {
                Prime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (Prime)
    {
        cout << "The given number is a Prime Number";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The given number is not Prime, i.e. it is composite";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `b == 0, 1` should produce warning, with appropriate flags.

Comment: As a beginner, you should start with a [good introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What is `if (b == 0, 1)` supposed to do? Hint: it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What makes you think the `for` loop is executed every time? What happens if you add some simple print statements to the `if` and `else` branches?

Answer (score 2):

You have a comma in this `if` condition:

```
if (b == 0, 1)
{
    Prime=false;
}
```

This will evaluate `b == 0`, but then discard the result and evaluate `if(1)`. That's causing `Prime` to always be set to `false`, then skipping the `else` clause entirely. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475043/1288) for why it behaves that way.)

If you want to check to see if `b` is equal to either 0 or 1, use:

```
if (b == 0 || b == 1)
```

Comment: I think this answer needs `if (b == 0 || b == 1)` which is presumably the test that OP was trying to create.

Comment: @TimRandall Ah, that makes more sense! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh thanks! But can you please tell what this | | symbol is called and what is its function? I don't think I have learnt about it yet

Comment: @PriyanshuMakwana That's called the logical OR operator. It's one operator used to combine logical (boolean) conditional statements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/logical-or-operator-pipe-pipe?view=msvc-160